# Spring Boot + Tomcat + EclipseLink causes: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eclipselink, tomcat8

I'm currently struggleing around with a Spring-Boot application that should use EclipseLink as JPa implementation and that app should run within a Tomcat 8 container. Unfortunatelly I'm not able to get it to work.

As far as I read I need to add the spring-instruments.jar as java command line argument (javaagent), but I read somewhere that tomcat 8 is not requiring that because it automatically decides which load time weaver it uses. Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong here?

Basically I get the following exception when I try to run the application:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    at foo.AppConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(AppConfiguration.java:57)
    at foo.AppConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a92e9feb.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$1(<generated>)
    at foo.AppConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a92e9feb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4dbaad1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at foo.AppConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a92e9feb.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ss.stock</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://raspberrypi:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/StockBatch</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version> 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And my Spring boot Configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("foo")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dmds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dmds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://raspberrypi:5432/stocks");
        dmds.setUsername("abc");
        dmds.setPassword("***");
        dmds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        return dmds;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("foo");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing", "JDBC");
        factory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size", "500");
        factory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode", "commit");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got a fix for the same ?